# Codeigniter logging every query

Tags: codeigniter

I have an extranet made with codeigniter that I want to log every users' editions to the database.
E.g. user1 created item1, user2 edited item2 - edit details, user2 deleted item3

Is there any easy way to capture all users' activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid there isn't an easy way to capture all users' activity built into CodeIgniter. However, you can make a master library which handles all users' activities and log your messages in this one place.

To expand on this idea, I have found creating a DAO library in which *all* database interactions must go through to be awfully handy.

Comment: can you share the link for the library?